# How to query between two dates in graphql

Tags: java, realm, graphql

I have a problem here regarding Realm queries in GraphQL.

Is it possible to query between two dates in graphql?

This is what I've tried:

```
query getStudents{
  student(query:"created_datime BETWEEN {'2018-02-24T14:59:43.842Z','2018-02-28T14:59:43.842Z'}"){
    id
    code
    name
    created_datetime
    modified_datetime
    status
  }
}
```

it occurs an error "Invalid Predicate".

How to query it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try:

```
student(query:"created_datime BETWEEN {'2018-02-24@14:59:43:842', '2018-02-28@14:59:43:842'}"){
```

> Notice the **@** instead of the **T** in question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an invalid predicate because you put `created_datime` instead of `created_datetime` in your query. That's happened to me before where you misspell a variable when attempting to query and it doesn't work.